# bash removes consecutive spaces from string

Tags: string, bash, quotes

I ran into a strange problem that I do not understand. Why are multiple spaces not present in the output of the following command?

```
$ d='A      B'
$ echo $d
A B
```

Comment: you need to wrap the `$d` in double quotes to preserve spacing, eg, `echo "${d}"`

Comment: See the bash [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Double-Quotes.html#Double-Quotes) on quoting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use in double quotes:

```
echo "$d"
```